# Change AVPlayer Orientation- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have looked at multiple ways to change the orientation (rotate 90degrees)  of an AVPlayer/AVPlayerLayer. The most common way I found was to do this:

```
playerLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2))
```

This what it looks like when I do that (on aspectfill):

[image]

As you can see, this doesn't work for me and I think it's because of the changes in xcode and swift over the years.

How would you rotate the AVPlayerlayer 90degrees now?

Thanks in advance!

Code used for AVPlayer:

```
var post: Post?

var avPlayer: AVPlayer?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startPlayingVideo()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func startPlayingVideo() {
    // get video onto the avplayer
    guard let videoUrlString = post?.postVideoUrl else { return }
    guard let videoUrl = URL(string: videoUrlString) else { return }
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
    // add the avPlayerLayer
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    //start Playing the video on the avPlayer
    self.avPlayer?.play()        
}
```