# Rotate UIImageView 90degrees - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rotation, imageview

I am trying to get an UIImageView to rotate, so it will look from this (in aspect fit):

[image]

To this: (sorry about the scale)

[image]

This is the code I used to try to rotate the imageView:

```
// rotate the imageView
   let transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
   self.imageView.transform = transform
```

This kind of works but, it will cut off most of the image, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of rotating the image view, why not rotate the _image_? Would that make sense?

Comment: @matt No, because I also want to use this to rotate a AVPlayerLayer added into a UIView. But, if you can maybe look at this post by me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110082/change-avplayer-orientation-swift Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change transform rotation like this:

```
yourImageView.transform = self.yourImageView.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
```